# match the unins000.exe if not 000

Tags: c#, regex, filenames

I'm using Inno Setup to create a simple setup for my application, A.
From a second application, B, I want to call to the `unins000.exe` of application A.

So I just use this code, and that works perfectly:

```
  //get a new process to start
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  //get the basic exe file to run (the uninstall)
startInfo.FileName = installPathA() + "\\unins000.exe";
  //start the uninstall
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
```

But in this case, I've hard coded it to  `000` in the `unins000.exe`.

What I was wondering about is would be possible to make it something like `unins...exe` where it will automatically check for what numbers should be on the `...`.

I thought at first to use `RegEx`, but this can only be used on a defined string right ? Or could I also use it in this way I want?
Or does someone know a better trick to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically check"? That there might be unistallers named unins123.exe or unins665.exe in the folder and the program should find it? If so, then this should find it:    startInfo.FileName = Directory.EnumerateFiles(installPathA(), @"unins*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).First();

Comment: yes, exactly what i was looking for :) thank you very much!  too bad i cant flag your comment as: answered

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx

The DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() takes a pattern that allows you to search for matches.